# install gzip and using gunzip command in Windows

Tags: mysql, gzip

Recently I have been following [this side](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php) and working on backup and restore mysql database into compressed file by gzip.

I have downloaded the gzip setup exe file from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm). After I install the package, I found that inside the bin folder, it has several files, but only `gzip` file with extension `.exe`, others such as `gunzip`, `zcat` files are without any extension, when I try to uncompress the `gz` file and restore to the specific mysql database with the following command

```
gunzip < C:\abc.sql.gz | mysql -u root -ppassword db_name
```

it comes out message `'gunzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I have register the gzip into path, and Windows does recognize the `gzip` command, but not other like `gunzip`.